# using 'And Where' in Many to Many relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have two models which have a many-to-many relationship.

```php
class User extends Model
{
    function cars()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class);
    }
}

class Car extends Model
{
    function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

I want to get users who used a specific set of cars:

```php
$car_selected = [1, 3, 6];

$users = User::when(count($car_selected) > 0, function ($q) use ($car_selected) {
    $q->whereIn('cars.id', $car_selected);
})
    ->get();
```

This gives too many results because of the 'whereIn' condition; what I want is 'whereAnd' something.

I tried this, but no luck.

```php
$users = User::when(count($car_selected) > 0, function ($q) use ($car_selected) {
    foreach($car_selected as $xx) {
        $q->where( 'cars.id', $xx);
    }
})
    ->get();
```

How can I get all users which have a relationship to cars 1, 3, and 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code provided doesn't make a lot of sense, but based on your explanation, you want to find a user who has a relationship with cars 1 **and** 3 **and** 6. Using `whereIn()` gets you users with relationships with cars 1 **or** 3 **or** 6.

Your attempt with multiple `where()` filters wouldn't work, as this would be looking for a single row in the pivot table with multiple cars, which obviously wouldn't be possible. Instead, you need to nest multiple [`whereHas()` relationship filters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) into [a single `where()` group](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#parameter-grouping) like this:

```php
$users = User::where(function ($q) use ($car_selected) {
    foreach ($car_selected as $car) {
        $q->whereHas('cars', function ($query) use ($car) {
            $query->where('car_id', $car);
        });
    }
})
    ->with(['cars' => function ($q) use ($car_selected) {
        $q->whereIn('car_id', $car_selected);
    }])
    ->get();
```

This is all assuming you've correctly set up your relationships and tables per Laravel standards.

Demo code is here: https://implode.io/anjLGG

Comment: Yes this is what I want .. yes this is  Answer for my case. Thank you..

Comment: Sorry for this. I am almost newbie here..and  I can not find the way to accept your answer ..  I can not see ✅  too. and there is someone's wrong reply as Answer. I can say I didnt accept that wrong code. I event commented that that is not correct. Anyway sorry for giving some kind of hurt..but noway to accept yours. thats why I commented your ID and answer.. If  you let me know how to correct this, I will do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `whereHas` method to query relationship:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

    User::whereHas('cars', function (Builder $builder) use($car_selected)
            {
                $builder->whereIn( 'cars.id', $car_selected);
            })->get();
```

For more infos, check the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: Thanks for reply.. But that is now what I want. Using 'WhereIn' can not get Intersected rows.  please read my question carefully..

Comment: so what do you mean by 'This gives *Combination* because of 'whereIn' condition' . What problem do you face ?

Answer (score 0):

as @miken32 explained, I need to nest multiple whereHas() relationship filters into a single where() group.

@miken32 proposed following..

```php
$users = User::where(function ($q) use ($car_selected) {
    foreach ($car_selected as $car) {
        $q->whereHas('cars', function ($query) use ($car) {
            $query->where('car_id', $car);
        });
    }
})
    ->with(['cars' => function ($q) use ($car_selected) {
        $q->whereIn('car_id', $car_selected);
    }])
    ->get();
```

And I guess following is enough .

```php
$users = User::where(function ($q) use ($car_selected) {
    foreach ($car_selected as $car) {
        $q->whereHas('cars', function ($query) use ($car) {
            $query->where('car_id', $car);
        });
    }
})->get();
```

Thanks.